# Php PDO Mysql selected value dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make an update form. In this update form is a dropdown list that is populated with value's from an mysql table. Now i got the expected values but i cannot get the right value to be selected (the one that belongs to the ID).

For example:

1. co_id = the record for contacts, thats the one im updating.
2. co_cs_id = the id of the company that belongs to the co_id, this is should be the selected value.

I got the following code:

```
echo "<td style width='30%'><select type='text' data-live-search='true' required data-live-search-style='startsWith' class='selectpicker form-control' name='co_cs_id' value='$contacts->co_cs_id'>";
$query = "  SELECT cs_id, cs_name
            FROM customers_suppliers            
            WHERE cs_status=0 
            ORDER BY cs_name";


            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    echo "<option value='{$cs_id}'>{$cs_name}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

This an example record:
[image: Record information before update form]

[image: Update form with wrong company value]

You can see that the company value is not the same.

Comment: The [<select>-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) does not have an value attribute. Not sure if that would screw it up though. What does your generated HTML look like?

Comment: have you tried removing the value from your select element. So far I can not see anything that is causing this to be wrong.

Comment: The page looks as follow: https://imgur.com/a/XwuZbSj The thing is that now test1 is selected while based on this record it should be test 3.

Comment: @C.Jacobs I am unable to view that link

Comment: How about this one? https://imgur.com/4m7isyc

Comment: @C.Jacobs I mean I just can't view it because I'm at work and they restrict the use of imgur for some reason

Comment: @C.Jacobs you want to show a specific value to be pre-selected right?

Comment: @RonakDhoot Exacly, the value thats linked to the record.

Comment: eww, dont use extract like that it pollutes the global namespace, increases memory and variables could affect code after it.. column called stmt etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `selected` attribute

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    if($cs_id == $co_cs_id) {
        echo "<option value='{$cs_id}' selected>{$cs_name}</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='{$cs_id}'>{$cs_name}</option>";
    } 
}
```

or in one line

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row);
    echo "<option value='{$cs_id}'".(($cs_id == $co_cs_id) ? "selected" : "").">{$cs_name}</option>";
}
```